# Code signer error in blackberry webworks application

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks

I have developed a Blackberry Webworks Application, code signed it and deployed it on my playbook.
The problem is that, I have made some changes to my existing application, generated the sigtool.p12 file and when i try to complile it using

**bbwp "MyReport.zip location" -gcsk myPassword -gp12 myPassword-buildId 2 -o "Output file locaiton"**

Iam getting the following error

```
[INFO]                  Parsing command line options
[INFO]                  Parsing bbwp.properties
[INFO]                  Validating WebWorks archive
[INFO]                  Parsing config.xml
[INFO]                  Populating application source
[INFO]                  Compiling WebWorks application
[INFO]                  Packaging the bar file
[INFO]                  Bar packaging complete
[INFO]                  Starting signing tool
barsigner error: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: http://www.rim
.net/Websigner/servlet/RDK-Waterloo
[ERROR]                 Signing failed
```

Answer (score 2):

RIM signing servers sometimes are down for maintenance or for another purpose. Try to sign your application later.

Comment: I'm guessing it applies to PlayBook as well, but http://isthesigningserverdown.com/ shows info on the Java signing servers.

Comment: The BlackBerry Dev twitter account @BlackBerryDev posts scheduled maintenance tweets regarding the signing servers a few hours ahead of time.

Comment: seems like this is the right answer?  but no tick?  this post agrees but Im having this issue at mo...  http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Tablet-OS-SDK-for-Adobe-AIR/Error-Server-returned-HTTP-response-code-502-for-URL-http-www/td-p/1387835